# JSON.parse string - unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

Im trying to parse a JSON response from a server using node but its coming through as a string like this for example:

```
"{name:'hello'}"
```

Here is how i've recreated the exact problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/x5sup14j/

I've tried `replace(/'/g, '"');` to remove the single quotes, and `JSON.stringify` as well as throwing in some `toString()`

I can't seem to figure this one out >.<

.

.

**EDIT**

I've built a node server to receive a request with some data that then proxies through to another server. I then save some information from the response (the http body) and return another object to the client side. Heres my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongojs');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.use('/login', function(req, res) {
    request.post(
        'http://192.168.1.53',
        { form: { req: 'auth',  cid: '1', em: req.body.em, pw: req.body.pw, rm: true} },
        function (error, response, body) {
            //var body = JSON.parse(body);

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 && body.success == true) {
                user.res = res;
                var cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
                database.createUser(cookies, req.body.em, req.body.pw);

            } else if (body.success == false) {
                res.json({success: false, error: body.success});

            } else {
                res.json({success: false, error: error});
            }
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON. It's not just the single quotes, `name` needs to be wrapped in double quotes too. This really ought to be fixed on the server side. You might be able to fix it on the client side, but it's going to be pretty tedious.

Comment: Before you try to "fix" it can you fix the source of the bad data? If not, there are other non safe ways to fix it.

Comment: No theres no way to fix it on the other server. I'll add the node.js code I'm using that is receiving the http response, maybe its something on my side i can fix because if i do the same thing through the console with ajax it comes back as a json object.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like HanSON to parse the incoming string, and then have it spit out valid JSON. https://www.npmjs.org/package/hanson

Comment: Matt Burland has the right answer. As does Timothy Strimple.

http://jsfiddle.net/x5sup14j/1/ -- your fiddle, updated with proper JSON, works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using SENCHA Ext.js module for handling JSON we are able to call the decode function that parses the json perfectly.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/JSON.html#Ext-JSON

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It is bad practice to depend on non-standard behavior by one particular library to deal with malformed JSON. Why don't you just emit correct JSON from the server?

Comment: Its not my server. Otherwise I would. I hate to use bad practice but sometimes there isn't really any other choice.